How can I serve vue template in html file using NodeJS express
I want to serve html files using NodeJS express but I don't want to create application in command line because I want to see how framework application' files related with others and folder structure. I already can serve html files and relate the database with client but also I want to serve vue files and use templates to import other html files.
This is my nodejs server.js file:
const express = require("express");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');

const loginPage = require('./routes/login.js');
const loginRequest = require('./routes/login-request.js');
const registerRequest = require('./routes/register-request.js');
const indexRequest = require('./routes/index.js');
const userDataFrontEnd = require('./routes/user-data-front-end.js');

const app = express();
const PORT=3000;

// Set the correct MIME type for JavaScript files
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.path.endsWith('.js')) {
        res.type('application/javascript');
    } else if (req.path.endsWith('.vue')) {
        res.type('text/html');
    }
    next();
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Use cookie-parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());


/**
 * Uses json format
 */
app.use(express.json()); 
// Add this line to parse URL-encoded data
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

/**
 * Routes
 */

/** @description Request to space wars */
app.use('/', loginPage);

/** @description Request to login user account */
app.use('/login-request',loginRequest);

/** @description Request to sign-up user account */
app.use('/register-request', registerRequest);

/**@description request to index */
app.use('/index', indexRequest);

/**@description request to get user data to front end vuejs */
app.use('/user-action', userDataFrontEnd);

app.listen(PORT , ()=>{
    console.log('Server listening on ' + PORT+' port.');
});

module.exports = app;


This is my html file located at /public/views/index-vue.html :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.prod.js"></script>
        ... other styles
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/index.css" />
        <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script> -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="module" src="/templates/base-template.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

This file to route index.html /routes/index.js:
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const router = express.Router();

const { tokenClass } = require('../utils/token');

const indexPath = '/public/views/index-vue.html';


router.get('/', (request, response) => {
    if (tokenClass.checkToken(request.cookies.user_token) !== -1)
    {
        response.sendFile(path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), indexPath));
        return;
    }
    response.redirect('/?token_expired');
});

module.exports = router;


This file a script to add vue template public/templates/base-template.js :
// base-template.js
import BaseTemplate from '../templates/base-template.vue';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(BaseTemplate)
}).mount('#app');


And this is my template file I want to serve /templates/base-template.vue :
<template>
<!-- Main div -->
<div class="main">
    <!-- isDataLoaded conditional div -->
    <div class="data" v-if="isDataLoaded">
        <!-- account_status conditional div -->
        <div class="account" v-if="account_status">

            ........ other htmls
            </div>    
        </div>
    <!-- isDataLoaded conditional div end -->
    </div>
<!-- Main div end -->
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            utoken: 'user_token',
            isDataLoaded: false,
            account_status: false,
            innerData: null
        };
    },
    methods: {
        ... methods...
    },
    async mounted() {
        .... scripts ...
        }
    }
};
</script>


But when I try to serve file I'm getting error like this :
base-template.vue:1 - Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "application/octet-stream". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.


How can I serve file using vue and nodejs?

.vue SFCs are for bundled app. It's not valid JS and you can't use it in a browser as is. Since you're using "cdn" kind of app, you can't do this https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html

@EstusFlask could you remind me the non-official runtime .vue compiler?

@AlexanderNenashev Hi, do you mean this one? https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader . It exists for such cases indeed and has to be used with caution

@EstusFlask thanks, luckily vue has compile to compile HTML into render functions
